# Angular - HostListener directive and pass value

Tags: angular, typescript, innerhtml

I am trying to pass a div with click event using 'innerHTML'.Since (click) wasn't working, I tried to use HostListener to get id. But it seems can't even pass id in the innerHTML.

HTML Code

```
<div [innerHTML]="show" detectClick></div>
```

Host Listener

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event.target.id']) onClick(id: any) {
    alert(`You clicked on ${id}`);
    this.test = id;
}
```

Code to be appended dynamically

```
this.show = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(`<div class="clickarea"><span id="123" (click)="showID('123');">x</span></div>`);
```

Link to [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jq9ky2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: I think you have already noticed that it doesn't render `id` in HTML. You can also search for `DomSanitizer`

Comment: Thank you for your kind suggestion. I have added DomSanitizer in the StackBlitz and it is now showing the id and HostListener is working. But (click)="showID('123')" is still not working. Any ideas how to fix that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use Angular specific attributes like `(click)` or `[prop]` inside `innerHTML`.

But yes, you can use event delegation through `@HostListener` decorator to get clicked `id`:

**detectclick.directive.ts**

```
import { Directive, Output, HostListener, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: '[detectClick]'})
export class DetectClick {

  @Output() detectClick = new EventEmitter();

  @HostListener('click', ['$event.target.id']) onClick(id: any) {
    this.detectClick.emit(id);
  } 
}
```

**parent.html**

```
<div [innerHTML]="show" (detectClick)="showID($event)"></div>
```

**[Forked Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yectj2?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: Life saver. Thank you!